# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Error TRAS0033E

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

This is my first time using `IBM Worklight`. I have [followed this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-aim1206-working-with-worklight-1/).

However, when I tried to run Worklight Development Server from the `Servers view`, I got the following error:

> TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for
>   class, with exception and then the server won't start.

I am using `Eclipse Kepler` and `Worklight 6.1`.

Some of the error code :

> E TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactoryBuilder with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:276)
>       at com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:337)
>       at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Answer (score 9):

Are you using Java JRE/JDK 8 by any chance?

Comment: @user3509545, as a follow up to Orlando's answer, check to ensure all of your software is in the supported category here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=66C745D01E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36

Comment: Yes, I am using JDK 8.

Comment: Ok, I believe Worklight Studio is not compatible yet with Java 8, so I suggest the following: 1) Get a JDK version 6 or 7. 2) Point Worklight Studio to use that JDK version. 3) Start Worklight Studio pointing to a clean workspace.

Comment: Had this same error and Java 8 was my issue.  I had to go to Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs and change the default JRE to JDK 1.7.  Then I had to make sure JDK 1.7 was on my build path for the actual project.  I restarted Eclipse and everything started working.

Comment: I am using java 1.8 and IBM Liberty server ,  connection has been failed. could you please help me on ths.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fixed setting to use Java 1.7 version.

1. On command prompt check java -version. Ensure that is 1.7;
2. Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Ensure that is JDK 1.7;

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old article. It is almost 2 years old.
Try this instead:

1. Download **Eclipse *Java EE* 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)**
2. Navigate to Help > Eclipse Marketplace > search for "worklight", install Worklight Studio 6.1.0.1
3. Once installed and Eclipse is restarted...
4. Proceed with learning Worklight (how to create applications, etc) via the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/)

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks for the reply. I have followed your step however I still get the TRAS0033E error when running the Worklight Development Server. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What steps are you taking to 'run' the server? If you are trying to do some type of manual start, see my answer about how this works.

Comment: See chart 27 of this module; is this what you are doing?  http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_01_Creating_your_first_Worklight_application.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to start the server anymore. Because Worklight Server V6.0.0 and later can support multiple Worklight projects, there are no longer Start Server and Stop Server menu options that are associated directly to the Worklight project. Instead, the server that is associated with a Worklight project is started automatically (if the server is not already running) when you perform an action against that server or adapter. For example, the target server starts when you use the Worklight Studio command Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server.

See [Working with multiple Worklight Servers in Worklight Studio](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_multiple_wl_servers_with_wl_studio.html?resultof=%22start%22%20%22server%22%20)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did. Right click on the app-name -> Run as -> Run on Worklight Development Server and voila the error messages shows up :(. I edit my post with some of the error messages.

Comment: Did you install any additional plug-ins?

Comment: I only installed 2 plugins : ADT Plugins and Worklight.