# Worklight 6.2 - Unable to start the server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

The server's console in Eclipse shows many errors after I clicked the "Play" button in the Server view in Eclipse to start Worklight Server.

The errors from the Console view can be viewed here: [paste2](http://paste2.org/8LBgHhCO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likley happens due to using Java 1.8 (see [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Error TRAS0033E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928837/ibm-worklight-6-1-error-tras0033e)).

Downgrade to either 1.6 or 1.7 and make sure to setup Eclipse to use the JRE of 1.6 or 1.7.

- On command prompt check java -version. Ensure that is 1.6 or 1.7
- Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Ensure that is JDK 1.6 or 1.7