# Unable to start Worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I am getting following error when I try to start the server in Eclipse

```
Launching WorkLight_new (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1/wlp-1.0.4.cl50120131011-1639) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_05-b13 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server WorkLight_new has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0055I: Server shutdown requested on Monday, September 29, 2014 at 5:49 PM. The server WorkLight_new is shutting down.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server WorkLight_new is ready to run a smarter planet.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server WorkLight_new stopped after 1 minutes, 0.818 seconds.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Dev environment:-
Windows 7 Pro x64
Eclipse J2ee Juno SR2 x64

JDK 1.8.0_05 x64

Worklight Server 6.2(online install)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

----Update----
I have uploaded the server startup logs in 2 parts on pastebin. Below are the URLs
Part 1 - http://pastebin.com/601dDV0b
Part 2 - http://pastebin.com/aY5t398D

I Hope this helps

Comment: What error? Nothing you have shown us is an error.

Comment: Greg, this is all i get in console. And the last line was shown in red, that why I mentioned it as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it say "WorkLight_new"? This name suggests to me that you have created a 'new' server to work with instead of the default-provided Worklight Development Server, but you do not provide any details on what you've done while creating it.

My suggestion to you is to first test with the default configuration. Easiest is to simply start Eclipse with a new workspace and start the default server instead. Otherwise, you need to provide something more substantial than what you provided in the question.

Additionally,
This may also happen due to using Java 1.8 (see [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Error TRAS0033E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928837/ibm-worklight-6-1-error-tras0033e)).

Downgrade to either 1.6 or 1.7 and make sure to setup Eclipse to use the JRE of 1.6 or 1.7.

- On command prompt check java -version. Ensure that is 1.6 or 1.7
- Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. Ensure that is JDK 1.6 or 1.7

Comment: I tried to start the default one, but that was even more messy, as when I try to start that server, my whole console fills up with error log(so long that I can't even capture the whole). But I have not deleted it. Only tried to create a new one. Please let me know if I have to provide the full logs of the original one?

Comment: Yes. Copy the errors and paste them in pastebin.com; provide links.

Comment: Try changing to Java 1.7 and also make sure that eclipse is setup to use 1.7 instead of the current 1.8.

Comment: Hi Idan, I followed your steps and they were really very helpful. Thank you very much. :) Now I am getting different kind of error, (http://pastebin.com/3PRSqSyJ). I tried to take help from this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921815/) but the solution is same as you have mentioned in this question i.e. change my JDK to 1.7.x, which I did. Can you please help more?

Comment: Now that you have Java 1.7, I would try with a new workspace.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but new workspace didn't imported the default server details. But what I observed is, after closing the eclipse(incl. killing all Java related process that were running) and restarting it, the server in the old workspace started well. I really appreciate your help. And I would like to have a conversation with you over Skype or phone regarding Worklight as I am doing a kind of R'n'D over here in my company for our upcoming native apps(Android/iOS). Please accept my invitation on Skype so that we can talk over it. Thanks once again.

Comment: If you are an IBM customer, you should get in touch with your IBM contact person in order to get answers to your queries.